# GeoServer: How can I set up a user/role so that it can add new layers and apply existing styles to those layers in a specific workspace only?

Tags: python, api, geoserver-rest-api

I've only just started using GeoServer in the last week, so apologies if I'm missing the obvious.

But I have set up GeoServer with a "data loader" user and role.  The user has read, write and admin roles in my new workspace.  Using curl, I've been able to upload geoTIFFs and apply styles (predefined and in the same workspace as the layers) using the following commands.

```
curl -u dataloader:####### -v -XPUT -H "Content-type: image/tiff" --data-binary @D:\Data\tiffs\Test.tif -d "<coverageStore><name>NewLayer</name><workspace>myworkspace</workspace><enabled>true</enabled></coverageStore>" http://###.###.###.###:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/coveragestores/NewLayer/file.geotiff?filename=NewLayer.tif

curl -v -u dataloader:####### -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>TestStyle</name></defaultStyle><styles><style><name>TestStyle</name></style></styles></layer>" http://###.###.###.###:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworkspace/layers/NewLayer
```

When I was happy with the commands, I switched to using REST API using python.

```
from geo.Geoserver import Geoserver
geo = Geoserver('http://###.###.###.###:8080/geoserver', username='dataloader', password='#######')
geo.create_coveragestore(layer_name='NewLayer2', path=r"D:\Data\tiffs\Test.tif", workspace='myworkspace')
```

And it correctly added the new layer, but when I tried to publish the style for the new layer

```
geo.publish_style(layer_name='NewLayer2', style_name='TestStyle', workspace='myworkspace')
```

It fails with 403.  If I use the Admin user and password, the line above works.  How can I set up a user/role so that it can add new layers and apply existing styles to those layers in a specific workspace only ??

Comment: check what URL the python is sending to, it might be the global endpoint and not the workspace specific one